# Need to find a wireless microphone with a specific design

Tags: microphones

I'm really interested in wireless microphones lately, especially I really like the designs of the vintage Sony WRT-866 and Azden WHX-PRO microphones.
I'm curious, are there any other alternatives like this? Compact size, preferably with a durable antenna on the back...[image]

Comment: Hi! I'm afraid this kind of question doesn't fall under [the topics covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), both because we don't handle "recommend a ____" questions, and because it's more about audio tech than music. You might try reverb.com, or the helpful agents at Sweetwater. But be warned, a vintage wireless mic probably needs a vintage receiver!